# ng build error showing up after upgrading angular 2.4 to angular 5.0

Tags: angular, npm, angular5

I have upgraded my angular 2.4 app to angular 5.0. after successful installation process whoich includes - cli upgrade and angular version, when im trying to do ng build. the folloing error show up. [image: error message] any idea how to solve it. i did npm install and then after ng build same error shows up.

below is my packge.json file  -

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "0.16.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "0.32.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.16.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "0.10.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "0.21.4",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "0.3.6",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "0.13.8",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "2.19.6",
    "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "1.33.4",
    "@types/moment": "2.13.0",
    "angular2-highcharts": "0.5.5",
    "angular2-tooltip": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "cytoscape-qtip": "^2.7.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "js-polyfills": "^0.1.41",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng-lightning": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.4.2",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "primeng": "^2.0.6",
    "qtip": "0.0.4",
    "qtip2": "^3.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.92",
    "@types/node": "6.0.68",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.4.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

UPDATE - 
AFTER INSTALLING NPM I AGAIN, WITH UPDATING ALL THE DEPENDENCIES AND DEVDEPENDENCIES, I GET FOLLOWING ERROR [image: EROOR IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

First see the exact **[`issue`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8407)** reported in angular-cli repo and it's a common issue when you upgrade, to resolve add the following in "dependencies" and Devdependencies too in your **`package.json`**

```
{
 "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
 "typescript": "^2.4.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your anglar application update process u have follow like : 2.4 to 4 and 4.0 to 4.4 and 4.4 to 5 step by step do it it will solve u r problem.
u see this link to follow
https://update.angular.io/